# Как разместить текст в самом низу блока div?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Мне нужно разместить текст в самый вниз, без использования `margin`.

Как это можно сделать?

```
<div style="height: 400px; background: #baa970;">
  <p style="vertical-align: bottom;">text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grid:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  align-items: end;
  height: 400px;
  background: #baa970;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

[Flex:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 400px;
  background: #baa970;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

[Position:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: #baa970;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Только конкретный элемент (на [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  background: #baa970;
}

.particular-item {
  align-self: flex-end; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="particular-item">text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы только text был в конце, так как в этом блоке будут еще другие итемы